# Issue styling multi date event in a calendar with SCSS

Tags: html, css, calendar, sass

I'm trying to build a calendar in SCSS and HTML, similar to this:

[image]

I'm trying to make a nice representation for events that span multiple days. You can see that I am using the class `.long-event` on dates that are part of a multi date event. The problem is, I can't seem to round off the ends properly. In my example dates `1st - 3rd` and `14th - 18th` are selected as long events, but the 1st doesn't have the rounded end, nor does the 3rd (but the 4th does) and the 14th does (which is correct) but the 18th doesn't (and again the next day does which is wrong) Below is an example of what I've done:

HTML:

```
<div id="calendar">
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>01</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>02</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>03</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>04</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>05</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>06</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>07</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>08</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>09</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>10</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>11</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>13</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>14</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>15</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>16</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>17</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date long-event">
    <p>18</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>19</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>21</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>22</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>24</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>25</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>26</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>27</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>28</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>29</p>
  </div>
  <div class="date">
    <p>30</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calendar {
  width: 300px;
  display: table;

  .date {
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: wheat; */
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;

    p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }

  .long-event {
    background: orange;
  }

  // First date in range
  :not(.long-event) + .long-event {
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  }

  // Last date in range
  .long-event + :not(.long-event) {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  }
}
```

And a jsFiddle of what I've done:

https://jsfiddle.net/k0112tbd/6/

Any help would be appreciated, especially if you know a better way of doing this. Using the plugin that I plan to use, I cannot add any additional classes to the beginning of the event or the end, so I need something clever :)

Andy

Comment: Can you use JS/jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was asleep ;) Yeah I'll be building it with a plugin called clndr.js so can use jQuery

Comment: If you can use JS/jQuery you can apply additional classes (or styles) to individual days, with more powerful selectors than with CSS alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately until previous sibling selectors are introduced in CSS this won't be possible. For now your most reliable option is jQuery.

Using jQuery you can add a class to each of the last days in the `.long-event` series.

The following will add a class of `.last` to the last day in each `.long-event` series:

```
$('.long-event + .date:not(.long-event)').prev().addClass('last');
```

which can then be styled using the CSS you already had (with a new selector):

```
.last {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

For the second issue, targeting the first `.long-event`, you can add an additional selector:

```
:not(.long-event) + .long-event,
.long-event:first-child {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
```

The important part there is the `.long-event:first-child`, which will always apply the rounded corners to the first `.long-event` in the calendar.

If you wanted to stick with jQuery for the first day in each `.long_event`:

```
$(':not(.long-event) + .long-event, .long-event:first-child').addClass('first');
```

then:

```
.first {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/k0112tbd/7/).

Comment: Okay I'm with you now, this looks good. Any idea on fixing the issue with long events that start at the beginning of the month, where there's no element before it? For example on my jsFiddle, 1st-3rd should have 1 and 3 capped off, but it's only 3?

Comment: Updated with the solution to the second issue.